# Can you override pseudo-class with stylus

Tags: css-selectors, stylus

I would love to be able to polyfill some css selectors, but am not sure how to (or if it is even possible).

For example, take an `:any()`, and rewrite it to compile out the css 2 version of the.

e.g.

```
:any( div, span ) > .foo
  background blue
```

and have it compile to

```
div > .foo,
span > .foo {
  background: blue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any mixin or function that could achieve this with stylus, but simply use hierarchical styling :

```
div
span
    & > .foo
        background blue
```

(you can try it here : http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/try.html)

Comment: It wouldn't be a mixin, it would require a custom function in stylus and the ability to programmatically define selectors. I am already using the way you suggest, it would just be neat to author in new styles is all :]